# NSTreeController: how do I get an object given the NSIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Maybe this is a silly question, but I can't find the right method in the documentation.

How do I find the object of a NSTreeController given its NSIndexPath?

Something like: `objectAtIndexPath:` is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ask the controller directly. First you get the controller's [`arrangedObjects`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTreeController/arrangedObjects), which will be an [`NSTreeNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/index.html) or a subclass.

`NSTreeNode` has [`descendantNodeAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTreeNode/descendantNodeAtIndexPath:), also returning a tree node object. *That* node's [`representedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTreeNode/representedObject) is probably what you're looking for.